# Toolbar button gravity for extended toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, android-toolbar

Im trying to set the position of my back navigation icon in my extended toolbar as follows:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:theme="@style/Toolbar"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/action_bar_height"
    app:buttonGravity="top"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
```

Checking the sources of toolbar we can see the following:

```
private void ensureNavButtonView() {
    if (mNavButtonView == null) {
        mNavButtonView = new ImageButton(getContext(), null,
            R.attr.toolbarNavigationButtonStyle);
        final LayoutParams lp = generateDefaultLayoutParams();
        lp.gravity = GravityCompat.START | (mButtonGravity & Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK);
        mNavButtonView.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }
}
```

Where `mButtonGravity` is assigned via

```
mButtonGravity = a.getInteger(R.styleable.Toolbar_buttonGravity, Gravity.TOP);
```

So reading this correctly, the gravity of my toolbar should already be `Gravity.TOP` if nothing is configured. However it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Please paste whole xml here

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I played around a bit and tested a couple of combinations and can say that button's gravity and `android:minHeight` don't want to be friends.

This should work fine:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/action_bar_height"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:theme="@style/Toolbar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
```

Comment: +1 This is the correct answer. Don't allow the `minHeight` to control your toolbar, it will screw up the gravity measurements. Always set the `minHeight` to the default size, and set your extended side as the layout height.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the icon on the top and the title on the bottom you can try something like this:

```
<Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="128dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:gravity="bottom" />
```

Using the attribute `android:minHeight` as the standard actionBarSize,the buttons and actions are positioned in the top. While using the attribute  `android:gravity` you can set the position of the title at the bottom.

Comment: how to place title adjacent to the back arrow?