# Android API 21 Toolbar Logo gravity not working in extended Toolbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, material-design, android-toolbar

I could successfully align Toolbar Title and Subtitle to top by setting Gravity to top. But its not working for Toolbar logo. Even after setting gravity to top, logo still aligned center. I want it to be aligned top like title and subtitle.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            app:titleMarginTop="18dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:layout_height="168dp"
            android:minHeight="56dp"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

[image]

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28478384/toolbar-button-gravity-for-extended-toolbar if it helps although i haven't tried it

Comment: Check the answer of Gabrile in the link above

Comment: @Raghunandan: Thanks. I have checked it. Still I cant change logo gravity. All others (title,subtitle) are changing gravity as expected.Logo is still at center.